# Function template parameter with expression in return type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-argument-deduction

I've encountered [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) this function signature

```cpp
template<int I, int J>
A<I+J> f(A<I>, A<J>);
```

I do not understand the implications of `A<I+J>`. The page points out an `expressions that uses type`- as a template parameters and backs it up with example of `A<I+J>` and `A<I-J>` as return types that introduce overload.

At first I thought it could be a syntax for taking return value from sum and sub implementations of `I` and `J` as those are integers in this example, but I was not able to reproduce a working example of this.

What those `A<I-J>` mean and how the expression deduction happens (if happens) here ?

Comment: Its adding `I` and `J` and returns `A<T>` where `T` is the result of the addition.

Comment: `I+J` in this context is the compile time calculation of sum the values for `I` and `J`. I.e. if you instantiate with `I==1` and `J==2`, the return will be `A<3>`.

Comment: You won't be able to create a "working" example of the overloads described in the linked page as they differ only in their return types. https://godbolt.org/z/o6v3jf5Mx

Comment: Return type doesn't participate in deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I was not able to reproduce a working example of this.

I propose the following compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int>
struct A 
{ };

template <int I, int J>
A<I+J> addA (A<I>, A<J>);

template <int I, int J>
A<I-J> subA (A<I>, A<J>);

int main()
{
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<A<7>, decltype(addA(A<3>{}, A<4>{}))> );
  static_assert( std::is_same_v<A<-1>, decltype(subA(A<3>{}, A<4>{}))> );
}
```

> What those A means and how the expression deduction happens (if happens) here ?

From the example you can see that the type returned from the call

```
addA(A<3>{}, A<4>{})
```

is `A<7>` and that the type returned from the call

```
subA(A<3>{}, A<4>{})
```

is `A<-1>`

Observe that the compiler deduces `I` and `J` from the arguments of the functions and calculates compile-time the values (`I+J` and `I-J`) of the returned types.

--- EDIT ---

The OP observes

> So the clue here is deduction happens for compile time VALUES rather than TYPES as these are specified.

Well... yes but in two steps.

The deduction happens, compile-time, deducing the *types* of the arguments. So are deduced `A<3>` and `A<4>` as *types*. This implies the deduction *also* of the *values* of the template arguments for `A`. So `I` is deduced as `3` and `J` is deduced as `4`.

> From this I assume that compiler will deduce type of `<A-J>` as output type of subtraction those two types represent, meaning `<int-int> = <int>`.

I suppose you mean "deduce the type `A<I-J>` as output type".

Yes for the substance, no for the terminology. I'm not a terminology expert but I try to explain.

The important point I want to stress is that (see also the Jarod42's comment) the return types of template functions/methods is *never* involved in the deduction of the template parameters.

In this case, the compiler deduce the types of the arguments, `A<I>` and `A<J>`, consequently deduces (compile-time) also the `I` and `J` values.

Having the `I` and `J` values, the compiler *compute*, compile time, the `I+J` and `I-J` values so construct the return types (`A<I+J>` and `A<I-J>`).

Comment: So the clue here is deduction happens for compile time VALUES rather than TYPES as these are specified. From this I assume that compiler will deduce type of <A-J> as output type of subtraction those two types represent, meaning <int-int> = <int>. I shall explore this with type deduction too.

Comment: @Wiktoor - Answer improved to better explain this points. Hope this helps.